# Possibility of Violating Second Law of Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

A common climate change denier argument is that back-radiation proposed by climate-change theory violates the second law of thermodynamics because it implies that a cold body warms a hot body.

My understanding of this argument is that it's incorrect because the cold body and warm body are both emitting thermal radiation, the thermal radiation from the cold body to the hot body slows the rate at which the hot body cools down and the thermal radiation from the hot body to the cold body warms the cold body up. When considered together, the overall heat flow is from hot to cold, no violation of the second law involved.

This explanation has made me wonder about the following scenario. Consider two black bodies of different temperature near each other in free space, connected by a unidirectional thermal radiation filter, such that thermal radiation from the cold body towards the hot body passes through but thermal radiation from the hot body to the cold body is blocked or redirected in some other direction. I'll assume that the filter is 100% efficient for this hypothetical example.

Would this system allow heat to flow from cold to hot? Would that flow be considered a violation of the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: What you're describing sounds kind of like [Maxwell's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon).

Comment: What are the cold and hot bodies in the denier's argument?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly In the denier's argument, the cold body is the atmosphere, the hot body is the earth's surface. The denier's argument is that climate change theory invokes backradiation, radiated energy from the atmosphere to the surface of the earth. Denier's claim the existence of backradiation violates the second law. Climate change theory proponents argue that the backradiation doesn't violate the second law because you have to consider the entire net heat flow which still goes from hot to cold. Denier's don't like this defense.

Answer (score 4):

> Would this system allow heat to flow from cold to hot? Would that flow be considered a violation of the second law of thermodynamics?

Yes, such a system would violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics. Therefore, we can conclude that unidirectional thermal radiation filters do not exist.

Comment: Indeed, they would be instances of Maxwell's demon.

Comment: @AndreaAlciato Very similar, although the original "Maxwell's demon" thought experiment worked with atoms/molecules rather than photons.

Comment: there is *something* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diode

Comment: @hyportnex those are not what the OP is describing. Thermal diodes do not transport energy against a temperature gradient.

Comment: you are right, my excuse is that I have no idea what the OP is describing

Comment: That's an interesting answer. Circulators are real-world examples of devices that allow radio frequency electromagnetic waves to be manipulated like this. If radiated thermal energy is similarly an electromagnetic wave, why are circulators at this frequency range impossible?

Comment: It isn’t a question of the frequency. Circulators push signal (low entropy) one way. When they do so they increase the entropy (insertion loss). They do not push noise (high entropy) one way. They are not a one way thermal filter even at RF frequencies

Comment: @Dale I have updated the question to refer to circulators rather than one-way thermal filters. I think my original terminology may have been miseleading and confusing. In this hypothetical scenario, I don't see why the thermal radiation from both black bodies wouldn't be signals that pass through the circulator as normal.

Comment: Please don’t do that. It is against the site policies to edit a question after it has received answers in a way that invalidates the answers received. I have reverted the question to the original. Please ask a new question about the circulators

Comment: @Nick'Tim'Spurry however, be aware that the answer for the circulators is going to be the same as the answer for the one-way filter. The issue is not what you call the filter nor what the frequency range is of the filter. The issue is the second law of thermodynamics. Any device which passively moves heat against a temperature gradient violates the law. So, the question should be worded to acknowledge that circulators must not allow that, explain why your understanding suggests they should, and ask why your understanding of circulators is incorrect.

Comment: @Dale - If you consider a black body as a transmitter of electromagnetic waves and therefore substitute electromagnetic transmitters for the black bodies, the circulator or uni-directional filter would operate as described without issue. The circulator can't distinguish between electromagnetic waves from a transmitter or black body, so why would it's behaviour change in a way that causes the system to break down when black bodies are involved?

Comment: @Nick’Tim’Spurry you really need to ask this as a full question.

Comment: @Dale I can ask a new question if that's really required. I feel like the existing question hasn't really been answered though.